# how to set group_concat_max_len with pandas

Tags: mysql, pandas, group-concat

In my sql, I have group_concat, but data will be cuted by GROUP_CONCAT(). So i set group_concat_max_len in my code like this below

```
engine = create_engine(xxx)
with engine.connect() as con:
    with con.begin():
        con.execute("SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=100000;")
        df = pd.read_sql_query(sql)
```

But it sometimes work well and sometimes does not work, is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: A statement cannot "does not work". It either is executed successfully or fails with some error message.

Comment: To debug the issue, you can try printing the value of ```group_concat_max_len``` before and after setting it in your code. If th issue doesn't come from that, check the MySQL server logs for any error messages.